# What determines if Firefox opens a PDF in itself?

Tags: firefox, pdf

I know Firefox has a built in PDF viewer, but my question is what determines if it opens using the external program or Firefox's viewer? It seems really random and I've experienced both. I'd prefer to always use one method. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for sure, but one way to influence this behavior is for the server to add a custom header to the response, e.g. `Content-disposition: attachment; filename=fname.pdf`. It is then up to the browser to decide what to do with the file, open it by itself or show a dialog allowing a user to save or open the file.

To answer your question: You could disable Firefox's internal viewer, instructions on how to do that are [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/disable-built-pdf-viewer-and-use-another-viewer). In short: Open the *Settings* page, select *Applications*, and set your preference for PDF files.

Comment: Why wouldn't you provide the instructions in the answer itself?

Comment: @Ramhound I _did_ include a short instruction, didn't I? One argument to include a verbatim copy would be that the referenced page could be removed at any time, but otoh, the instructions could change for a future version of Firefox, and I expect that page to be updated sooner than my answer :-)

Comment: Does not matter if the instructions change in the future.  The answer today  with the current version of Firefox, which we can assume the author is using, are those instructions so they should be contained in the answer itself.

Answer (score 1):

To download:

```
Content-Description: File Transfer
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=...
```

To open in browser:

```
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=...
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```